# Get ng-model value in controller when using bootstrap ui radio button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

I can't seem to get the value of my radio button back into the controller...

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group-wrap">
  <div class="btn-group listBtn text-center">
    <label uib-btn-radio="0" ng-change="newDataset()" ng-model="changeDataset" class="btn btn-default">0</label>
    <label uib-btn-radio="1" ng-change="newDataset()" ng-model="changeDataset" class="btn btn-default">1</label>
    <label uib-btn-radio="undefined" ng-change="newDataset()" ng-model="changeDataset" class="btn btn-default">undefined</label>
  </div>
</div>
<p>filter {{changeDataset}}</p> //i see the change here!!
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.changeDataset = undefined


$scope.newDataset = function () {
  console.log('new dataset function called');
  console.log('the dataset= '+$scope.changeDataset) //but it just returns undefined here!!!
  console.log('the vacated= '+$scope.filter.vacated)
};
```

It recognises that the function is running, but it always just logs `undefined`.

Comment: dont use same ng-modal for all radio buttons

Comment: If the radio buttons are linked together (ie only one choice possible) then he needs to keep the same ng-model for them.

Comment: that just breaks the radio buttons...?

Comment: Did you declared '$scope.changeDataset' ? before using it into function?

Comment: @the_mishra yes, it still doesn't pick up the value of the radio button...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `ng-model="changeDataset"` to `ng-model="$parent.changeDataset"`

$parent -  maps to the the scope containing the current scope

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, the `undefined` appears in console because you try to log `$scope.filter.vacated`, which is set to `undefined`.

Here is a snippet demo of your code working:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.filter = {
    vacated: undefined
  };
  
  $scope.newDataset = function () {
    console.log('new dataset function called');
    console.log('the dataset= ' + $scope.changeDataset);
    console.log('the vacated= ' + $scope.filter.vacated);
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
    <pre>{{changeDataset}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label uib-btn-radio="0" ng-change="newDataset()" ng-model="changeDataset" class="btn btn-default">0</label>
        <label uib-btn-radio="1" ng-change="newDataset()" ng-model="changeDataset" class="btn btn-default">1</label>
        <label uib-btn-radio="undefined" ng-change="newDataset()" ng-model="changeDataset" class="btn btn-default">undefined</label>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesnt work on my machine... could it be to do with the bootstrap / angular version? angular=1.5.9 bootstrap = 3.3.7

Comment: @Janey Nah, don't think so. Maybe a typo error somewhere? Check again, try to compare with my snippet... :-)

Comment: nope, copy and pasting to my code still returns undefined for $scope.changeDataset...